# Displaying time series data by changing object color in QGIS

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am looking to visualize the changes in lake chemistry over time by varying the color of the lake(s) as rendered on the map.  I have found the time manager plugin, that seems to be close to what I am looking for but I am not able to coax it to do what I want.

Ideally I would be able to put a slider on my map that would allow the user to select the date and easily move the slider back and forth to visualize the changes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you:

- Create a style for the different colours (Categorised, Graduated etc.)
- Create a field in the attribute table which contains the time in a suitable format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD)
- Use this field when adding a layer in the Time Manager plugin:

  [image: Example layer]
- Change the *Time frame size* to suit your requirements:

  [image: Settings]
- Enable the layer, make sure the plugin is switched on (with the convenient power icon light up as green) and hit the *Play* button. Hopefully now you should be good to go!

---

Some references:

- [Time Manager on GitHub](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager) (readme section is at the bottom)
- [Example shown on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkfoFFy-bao)

Comment: Hmm, this is what I did.  Is YYYY a valid format?   Note: stored as an int in the file.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I have answered my own question about the year format.  I updated the table to one of the supported date formats an the above approach worked like a charm.

Comment: @craigmcg - Glad you got it working =)